# Kendo UI Angular - Column titles hidden in Detail Grid with locked column

Tags: javascript, angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

Using a master-detail grid and with at least one locked column in the detail grid, the titles of the detail grid columns disappear (except the titles of the locked columns).

It looks like the width of the .k-grid-header > .k-grid-header-wrap element is not calculated correctly.

Note: The titles are visible and seem to work as intended if all columns fit in the width of the grid initially.

See this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kcHOhFAG31gusyG0f9AK?p=preview) for more details

```
@Component({
    providers: [CategoriesService],
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
      <kendo-grid
          [data]="view | async"
          [pageSize]="pageSize"
          [skip]="skip"
          [sortable]="true"
          [sort]="sort"
          [pageable]="true"
          [height]="550"
          (dataStateChange)="dataStateChange($event)"
        >
        <kendo-grid-column field="CategoryID" width="100"></kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column field="CategoryName" width="200" title="Category Name"></kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column field="Description" [sortable]="false">
        </kendo-grid-column>
        <div *kendoGridDetailTemplate="let dataItem">
            <category-details [category]="dataItem"></category-details>
        </div>
      </kendo-grid>
  `
})

@Component({
    selector: 'category-details',
    providers: [ProductsService],
    template: `
      <kendo-grid
          [data]="view | async"
          [pageSize]="5"
          [skip]="skip"
          [pageable]="true"
          [scrollable]="'scrollable'"
          (pageChange)="pageChange($event)"
        >
      <kendo-grid-column field="ProductID" title="Product ID" width="250" [locked]="true">
      </kendo-grid-column>
      <kendo-grid-column field="ProductName" title="Product Name" width="250">
      </kendo-grid-column>
      <kendo-grid-column field="UnitPrice" title="Unit Price" format="{0:c}" width="250">
      </kendo-grid-column>
      </kendo-grid>
  `
})
```

[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnQ6i.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the k-grid-header-wrap element has a width of 0px at initial load. This width is set as an inline style by Kendo using Javascript. Resizing the window, the frame/splitter, or the grid seems to remedy the problem and might provide a way for you to do a work-around. If you have access to the Kendo source code for the grid you may be able to trace the bug by searching for k-grid-header-wrap.

I suspect this is a Kendo bug and should be logged at Kendo's GitHub issue tracker.

Comment: I also made a post at Kendo's issue tracker, but wanted to see if anyone of the SO community had and solved this issue before

Comment: Could you please reference to appropriate issue? Anyone solved this problem?